# After migrating some tables from magento 1.7 to 2.1.8 now unable to register new customer account

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool

I used this tutorial to migrate website  `https://www.pinpointdesigns.co.uk/migrating-data-from-magento-1-to-magento-2-using-the-data-migration-tool/`

and now after doing this when I try to register new user I got a error

```
Please enter user email and id
```

anyone have idea whats going on ?

I have to include something for customers etc ?

Comment: Enable developer mode. Check your logs. Debug this and return with some more information. There are many thing that can go south after a migration.

Comment: @Vulpea  someone told me that I have to include some kind of formkey in  customer module ?

Comment: this one  <?php / @noEscape / echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>     is this issue ? where I have to place that ?